# Jackson deserialize with missing fields dos not throw exception

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

Trying with that simple app

```
public class JsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"name\":\"john\"}";
        System.out.println(json);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Person person = objectMapper.readValue(json, Person.class);
        System.out.println(person);
    }

    @Data
    private static class Person {
        String name;
        Integer age;
    }

}
```

I don't understand why it does not throw an exception.

It gives me

```
{"name":"john"}
JsonTest.Person(name=john, age=null)
```

I also tried adding `objectMapper .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, true);` or even add `@NotNull` or `@JsonProperty(required = true)` in front of `Integer age` but it has no effect.

The only solution I found is, after the deserialization, to test if age is null.

Is there another solution ?

Comment: Did you try to add `@AllArgsConstructor` to Person class?

Comment: Just tried.  With only `@AllArgsConstructor` I got `(no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value`.  I also added `@NoArgsConstructor` but same result.  No exception.

Comment: and what about `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@JsonCreator))`?

Comment: You mean `@Data @AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@JsonCreator))     private static class Person` ?
 It gives me `Argument #0 has no property name, is not Injectable: can not use as Creator`